# Mathematic formula to split (X,Y) data based off line

Tags: sql, excel, symbolic-math

I have a group of data with X and Y coordinates, and I would like to split them into two different groups (called N and S), based off a line that runs down the middle of them, and whether the points sit north or south of that line. The line has a point origin of 322972, 6566850 and is angled at a bearing of 131.4.

What is a mathematic formula I can apply to each datum to determine if it sits to the north or south of the line? Ideally this would be an IF statement in excel.

I can only get as far as IF Y>=6566850,"N","S". See attached sample data:

**Point origin of line, bearing 131.4 degrees**
322972, 6566850

**Example point north of line**
323072, 6566950

**Example point south of line**
322872, 6566750

Comment: Share sample data and the expected output, also, specify whether you want an SQL solution or an Excel solution.

Comment: Construct a normal (perpendicular) to the line. A point is one side of the line or the other according to the sign of (point - base point) . normal, where "." is the scalar (i.e., dot) product. All points with positive sign are on one side, all negative on the other, and all zeros are on the line itself. The base point can be any point on the line, although it makes sense to choose a point that's more or less in the middle of the points you want to test. This test amounts to `IF A*X + B*Y + C > 0, ...` for some values of A, B, and C which you can derive from the normal and base point.

Comment: @ahmed, I have added some sample data and specified I would like an excel formula.

Comment: @Robert Dodier, I understand the concept of creating a line normal to the cutoff line, and everything above this will be N and everything below this will be S, but I don't quiate understand how to execute this. Are you please able to give me an example using the sample data I have added?

Comment: If you rewrite that line to the form `y = ax + b` then for a given X you can calculate the Y for the line. Is your actual Y higher (N) or lower (S)? How to handle equal (on the line)?